# How to check company firewall

Tags: proxy, firewall, windows-firewall

I am trying to ping to an external APIs IP address. But the command times out sooner than its completion.

Now I think the company firewall and proxy might be a hindrance in this.

How do I check the firewall settings? Which specific option do I need to examine?

Any guidance will be greatly appreciated.

```
C:\Documents and Settings\xxxxxx>tracert 103.16.xxx.xx  

 Tracing route to 103.16.xxx.xx over a maximum of 30 hops  

   <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.xx.x  
   24 ms    36 ms    34 ms  10.70.144.169  
  118 ms   164 ms   148 ms  10.70.140.182  
   *        *        *     Request timed out.  
   *        *        *     Request timed out.
```

Edit: Updated traceroute

Comment: Use a **traceroute** instead of a ping.  Where does the failure happen?

Comment: @Zoredache updated the question

Comment: Right, so now you know where the failure seems to be happening.  Contact your IT dept.

Comment: Is proxytunnel helpful here? Or only ask the people in charge

Comment: If this is for a work-related task, then you should be working with your IT department to get the firewall configured so you can get your work done.

Comment: I somehow always get entangled in complex issues when help is a desk away! Thanks for your inputs!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The elevated ping times in your `tracert` point to internal network issues. Contact your system administrator for assistance. Try also running `tracert` on other sites (such as superuser.com) to see if similar results appear. It's possible the firewall filters outgoing ICMP, too.